# Can't install Minecraft Forge .JAR file in Windows 8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge, windows-8.1

I am trying to install the new Forge for v1.15 on my GF's Windows 8 PC. The file I am getting marked installer is a .JAR file. Now when I run this same file on my Windows 7 PC, it opens and runs just fine, but when I try on her machine it asks what to open it with, and I don't know where to go for that. Just so you know, Minecraft works just fine as is, but we can't play modded together otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Answer posted by OP in comments

---

ahh hah, ok so a little more digging and i found out that for some odd reason, even though the game runs just fine, but she didnt have java installed, or at least didnt have the full program. i have since gone to the java website and installed the most up to date java program, and the tried the .jar file once again and it ran perfectly. so i guess first thing to do would be check your java version. i hope this helps anyone in a similar place